# How to set the DOS/Windows PATH variable: To SET or not to SET?

Tags: shell, path, dos

This one is so embarrassingly basic that I am, well, embarrassed to ask, but here goes: Do I need to write

```
SET PATH=c:\mynewpath;%PATH%
```

or is

```
PATH=c:\mynewpath;%PATH%
```

sufficient? The output is always `c:\mynewpath;...` so I figure maybe both are OK? Any other variable than PATH only works with `SET`, so `PATH` must be special. If that is so, are there any other "magic" variables like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of paths is the order they are searched. Imagine you had two programs of the same name. Which folder is searched first, as the search stops when the file is found, is the file that will run.

You should put your folder last so you don't force Windows to search unlikely folders first for all other commands.

There is no difference to how you set the path.

Comment: Thanks - search order is clear and is not what I asked.

Comment: Then what you ask is unclear. Type `path /?`, `set`, and `set /?`

Comment: Thanks - the first question was, is there a difference between `SET PATH=...` and `PATH=...`. I am quite convinced the answer is no, as you also pointed out - because PATH doubles as a command AND a variable, even though it looks like a variable like its parallel in Unix. The second question is, are there other DOS/Windows constructs that are simultaneously variables and commands?

Comment: Also type `help` and compare it with `set /?`. But no. Remember this is MSdos rules.

Comment: Good hint. So `help path` shows me there is a third option to set the path:

    PATH c:\mynewpath;%PATH%

I will accept your solution as I think we have exhausted the PATH discussion now. Thanks again